# Is there a taskbar system monitoring tool on Windows 11?

Tags: network-monitor, windows-11, taskbar

I want to display the current network speed, the read/write speed of the hard disk, CPU and memory usage in taskbar, **especially network and hard drive usage**, so I can detect unusual activity in time.

Before I used "[XMeters](https://entropy6.com/xmeters/)" on Windows 10, but now it no longer updates and doesn't support Windows 11; I found a similar tool called "[TrafficMonitor](https://github.com/zhongyang219/TrafficMonitor)", but it seemed unsafe, this is a VT report on [TrafficMonitor_V1.84.1_x64.zip](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/7217c298d56936c58e36f8b98fcea50537ae935d57bc85c946c6385b6ffdd7cc).

Is there a safe tool that similar [XMeters](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fdragoninformatica.it%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2018%2F05%2FXMeters-principale.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fdragoninformatica.it%2Fsoftware%2Fmonitorare-le-risorse-del-pc-con-xmeters%2F&tbnid=9LA2Ec5CLZsgeM&vet=12ahUKEwjXg-qG95z9AhXNO0QIHd2sCroQMygSegUIARDSAQ..i&docid=v4JZ1_5nm-yC3M&w=800&h=445&q=xmeters&ved=2ahUKEwjXg-qG95z9AhXNO0QIHd2sCroQMygSegUIARDSAQ) or [TrafficMonitor](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.thewindowsclub.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F06%2FCheck-CPU-network-disk-usage-in-system-tray-using-Xmeters-1.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.thewindowsclub.com%2Fcpu-network-disk-usage-xmeters&tbnid=qV_qLjbl_4uLHM&vet=12ahUKEwjXg-qG95z9AhXNO0QIHd2sCroQMygHegUIARC8AQ..i&docid=Xz1wKyGp2FrX5M&w=600&h=364&q=xmeters&ved=2ahUKEwjXg-qG95z9AhXNO0QIHd2sCroQMygHegUIARC8AQ#imgrc=qV_qLjbl_4uLHM&imgdii=aE0dlA3fbkwXSM)?

Sorry for my bad English and thanks for your comments and suggestions!

Comment: Welcome to our community Doit! Your English is actually quite good!

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [gadgets](https://8gadgetpack.net) for a while. They are like android widgets.  In particular **Network Monitor** or **Network Meter**.

> **INTERNET & NETWORK [x5]** Sidebar
> FOR REAL GEEKS ONLY — INTERNET & NETWORK MONITORING GADGETS.
>
> Use all possibilities of internet agents with maximum effect and minimum effort. With these Windows 11 and Windows 10 internet gadgets, you can check your network in a minute. You can monitor your connection and/or NIC status, external IPv4/IPv6 address, DNS, MAC address and much more. Use any browser straight from the desktop and gain any important information you need in a few seconds. These mini-applications can be very useful helpers. Works with wired and wireless networks.

I will add a screenshot shortly.

I  sm not asdocited with them.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how detailed you need it to be, but [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) has smaller tray icons with graphs that you can enable in Options -> Tray Icons. It's a very popular app thanks to its other features and surely works with Windows 11.

And if you'd prefer something more like gadgets recommended in a different answer, I would say that [Rainmeter](https://www.rainmeter.net/) is the best app for that purpose with lots of options and extensions.

Comment: Thanks, but not I want; I want to show the percentages of hardware usage and network speed in  taskbar, like TrafficMonitor.

Comment: Process Explorer does it in tray part of taskbar as explained. https://temp.sh/ASegO/2023.02.16_14.46.33.842_Process_Explorer_-_Sysinternals_www.sysinternals.c.png

Comment: Thanks, but I mean I want to show that like [trafficmonitor](https://github.com/zhongyang219/TrafficMonitor/blob/master/Screenshots/taskbar_item_settings.png). I want to directly display the read/write speed of the hard disk and the network speed without moving the mouse over it to display it. This function is already available in the task manager. If you can't see it directly in real time, what's the difference with me watching it in the task manager?

Answer (score 0):

[Tray Monitor](https://github.com/strayge/tray-monitor) might be what you are looking for, it replaced XMeters for me on Windows 11.